# launchpad complains about missing maven-site-plugin but I do not use it at all

Tags: java, maven, launchpad, libreplan

I am a Java and Maven newbie. There, I said it :-)

I am also responsible for an open source Java/maven project called LibrePlan.

When building ubuntu packages all works fine and I get deb's.
When building Ubuntu packages on Launchpad only the build for Trusty works. All others fail and the build process complains about a missing maven-site-plugin.

Why? I do not use that plugin at all anywhere in any of the pom files.

The log for one of the failed builds is here:

https://launchpadlibrarian.net/205758137/buildlog_ubuntu-precise-amd64.libreplan_1.4.1-9.precise_BUILDING.txt.gz

Can somebody please give me a hint where I should look into?
I increased verbosity, added the option to display the dependency tree, but I still can not see why this is going wrong.

It could be something incredably simple, but the question remains; what?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since launchpad buildservers have no connection to the Internet, dependencys can not be resolved unless the artifacts are uploaded with the sourcecode using a local repo.